# Replace failed disk in RAID 1

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

two days ago one of my two drives in my software RAID 1 (that was setup using gnome-disks) configuration failed. I could not access the files in the meantime. After short research it seems that I have to replace the failed disk and rebuild the RAID to access my files again. So no problem today I got my replacement disk, removed the old broken drive from the raid and tried to add the new drive to the disk.

(Before I copied the partition layout from the working drive with: `sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sda`)

When I try to add a new disk to my RAID (that shows up in my gnome-disks) with `mdadm —manage /dev/md0 —add /dev/sda`, I run into this error:

```
mdadm: Cannot get array info for /dev/md0
```

The same thing happens to basically any operation using `mdadm` on my /dev/md0.

**How can I get my RAID back working?**

Some info:

Ubuntu 15.04 (64bit)

```
mdadm --version
```

*mdadm - v3.3 - 3rd September 2013*

```
uname -a
```

*Linux Z97X 3.19.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 14 21:43:37 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

```
cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdb[0](S)
      976627383 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>

mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : PC:0
           UUID : XXXXXXXX:7af47836:XXXXXXX:d7360235
         Events : 3569

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       16        -        /dev/sdb
```

*Why is **Raid Level : raid0** when I setup this as raid1 in gnome-disks / it's shown as raid1 in gnome disks?*

> And one question in general: My understanding when I put up my RAID 1
>   was that if one disk fails I can still access my data because data is
>   mirrored. But when the disk failed this was obviously not the case.
>   Why? Is my understanding of RAID 1 wrong?